# Powershell Error when run the script automatically

Tags: python, powershell, server

I was using the following code `cmd /c $hash > $in 2>&1` to run a specific executable file using powershell. Here are the issues i face

1. This commands works in PC but not servers.
2. This commands can run perfectly in manually way in server, but when schedule, it hit into error as following

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec cant encode characters in position 33-35: character maps to undefined

Kindly help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know that I have faced same kind of issue when developing script in python & after lot of search I have found that I am facing `charmap` issue because of encoding issue.

What I need to do is set `utf-8` as default encoding & after setting it in my python script I am able to solve above issue.

Try to set proper encoding while reading file or opening file & hope you will find solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi, i am new here, could you please help to teach me on how to do that? the script is all powershell and no python is in use. but the error show pyton.

Comment: I have not much idea about powershell because I have never worked on it.Python to convert string to UTF-8 is like using `string.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')`.Do some search how to set encoding in powershell may you will find solution for your problem.